# Android Compilation Error - Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, kapt

Today I was trying to build an Android Project, but I'm getting the follow error below.

I'm having to find a way to figure out a solution for that.

Somebody have any idea about what's going on?

```
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Compilation error. See log for more details
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:163)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:156)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:14)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.run(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:122)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:146)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:141)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runJvmCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:81)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithKotlincTask.compile(KaptWithKotlincTask.kt:98)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor793.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:47)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:476)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:461)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:444)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:93)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:237)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:208)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:69)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 34 more
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s
```

In time, I think the `build.gradle` file can help to understand whats happening.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    testBuildType "debug"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "###############"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            versionNameSuffix ""
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            versionNameSuffix ".DEBUG"
        }
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
        unitTests.all {
            jvmArgs '-noverify'
        }
        animationsDisabled = true
        execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
    }
}

dependencies {
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0"
    implementation project(":core")
    implementation project(":common")
    implementation project(":security_token")
    implementation project(":security_device")
    implementation project(":security_monitoring")
    implementation project(":ui_components")
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-scope:$koin_version"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-java:$koin_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-common:2.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$androidx_legacy"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$google_material"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0" //:$supportx_version
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"// $supportx_version
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0" // $support_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraint_layout"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:$androidx_preference"
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gson_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp_version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxjava_version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxandroid_version"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:$rxandroid_version"
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.8.3', { exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' }
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebase_messaging_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$firebase_config_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:$firebase_dynamic_links_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.7'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:$safetynet_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.comscore:android-analytics:5.7.0'
    implementation 'net.take:blip-chat:2.1.23'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.7'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.github.sharish:ShimmerRecyclerView:v1.3'
    implementation 'io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation "com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:$new_relic_version"
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.8.20@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation files("libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi_1.2.2.jar")
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$play_services_auth"
    implementation 'net.openid:appauth:0.7.1'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    testImplementation project(":testutils")
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:$mockk_version"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:$robolectric_version"
    testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
    testImplementation ("org.koin:koin-test:$koin_version")
    androidTestImplementation project(":testutils")
    androidTestImplementation("io.mockk:mockk-android:$mockk_version") { exclude module: 'objenesis' }
    androidTestImplementation 'org.objenesis:objenesis:2.6'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.rx.idler:rx2-idler:0.9.1'
    androidTestImplementation ("org.koin:koin-test:$koin_version") { exclude module: 'objenesis' }
    androidTestUtil "androidx.test:orchestrator:$androidx_test"
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

If more information is needed, please let me know.

Thanks for while! []

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your module's `build.gradle` file? My suspicion is that you haven't included the `kapt` plugin, as:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Comment: I edited the question with buid.gradle.

But, anyway, the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` is already on the file.